# algorithm to accomplish comparing two arrays with user define criteria

Tags: algorithm

I want to compare tow float arrays' value. But it may be different from other criteria. Here is how I define which array is the best.

Say we have two array named `a`,`b`.First, we compare the max value of these two array, and the array with smaller max value wins. If they have same value, then we can divide each array into two parts. The first part is `a[1:max_loc(a)-1]` and `a[max_loc(a)+1,len(a)]`, and `b` is similar. Then we use the same criteria on `a[1:max_loc(a)-1]` and `b[1:max_loc(b)-1]` to see which array has the smaller max value. If they have the same max value on these intervals, then divide them to smaller arrays and do the same comparison. We also do the same thing for the `a[max_loc(a)+1,len(a)]` and `b[max_loc(b)+1,len(b)]`. Until we find smaller max value on the same intervals, the program end and print out the best array.

What's the algorithm to fulfill this comparison?

P.S. these two arrays may have different length.

Comment: You have already described command-and-conquer algorithm - just implement it. It is naturally recursive, so recursive implementation would be the simplest. (I assume that possible optimizations like BIT are not needed at this stage)

Comment: @MBo I can only find divide and conquer algorithm, while command and conquer is a PC game, is it a typo? And what is BlT? I'm not familiar with algorithm because I didn't major in CC or ES.

Comment: Of course, divide and conquer ;) I think, you don't need BIT (binary indexed tree, Fenwick tree) yet.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, what you search is somewhere already on the Internet :

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960118.html

Here you got 2 examples with full explanations which follows the divide and conquer idea (MergeSort and QuickSort)